# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in gulp

Tags: gulp

hi i will try to learn gulp but at start i have an error in my simple hello world. can anybody help me?

my gulp version is:
CLI version 3.9.0
Local version 4.0.2

my .babelrc file :

```
{
  "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env" ]
}
```

my gulpfile.babel.js file :

```
export const hello = (done) => {
  console.log('hello');
  done();
}
```

my package.json file :

```
  "name": "meatheme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp build --prod",
    "bundle": "gulp bundle --prod"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-wp-pot": "^2.5.0",
    "gulp-zip": "^5.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.43.4",
    "vinyl-named": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1",
    "yargs": "^15.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  }
}
```

and when i run gulp hello is see this in terminal.

```
[16:47:07] Failed to load external module babel-core/register
[16:47:07] Failed to load external module babel/register
/home/mehdi/Work/Meacodes/Mea template/mea0.1/gulpfile.babel.js:16
import gulp from 'gulp';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:203:12)
    at module. Exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:51:3)
```

do you know where is my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was advised to write *"type": "module"* to file package.json to the very end of the file
since node otherwise does not consider js files as ES modules, outside of which you still cannot use the import statement)
(in the browser we do modules through the type attribute of the script tag)